# Can't pip3 install paramiko on cloud shell

Tags: python, shell, pip, cloud

for some reason I can't install paramiko using pip3, I get this error when utilising
"pip3 install paramiko" within cloud shell on a VM

```
      copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/cffi
      copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/cffi
      copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/cffi
      copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/cffi
      copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/cffi
      copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/cffi
      copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/cffi
      copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/cffi
      copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/cffi
      running build_ext
      building '_cffi_backend' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-37
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/c
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -ffat-lto-objects -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-37/c/_cffi_backend.o
      c/_cffi_backend.c:15:10: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
       #include <ffi.h>
                ^~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
  
      ----------------------------------------
  Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-rdvno1af/cffi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-hxypfg21/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-7gfhuj8z --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-rdvno1af/cffi/
  
  ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-7gfhuj8z --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools>=40.8.0 wheel "cffi>=1.4.1; python_implementation != 'PyPy'"" failed with error code 1 in None
```

Anyone have any idea on what I'm missing here that doesn't let it install?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error%3A+ffi.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Comment: `libffi-dev` and `python-dev`